# Stop a timer from another page

Tags: c#, timer, windows-phone-8

This is WP8 project. I have the following timer that "loops" every 3 seconds.

```
private void temperatureTimer()
{     
     System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();      
     dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 3000); // 3s
     dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
     dt.Start();              
}

void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var obj = App.Current as App;
    if (obj.off == true) //global variable 
        dt.Stop();
    Temperature z = new Temperature(); //runs some code...
}
```

I want to stop when the user clicks a button from another page.

I have tried to stop it using a global variable and setting it to true when the user clicks the button from the other page but the timer stills on.

Comment: I'm surprised a DispatcherTimer would run when the page isn't active. That said, the global variable should work. Are you sure the timer keeps ticking? Do you have the same behavior if you add a `return` after stopping it? `if (obj.off == true) { dt.Stop(); return; }`

Comment: EventHandler can be used to notify from another page to the first page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global variables work. I had to rebuild my project, for some reason it wasn't working like it should.

Answer (score 0):

Either declare your DispatcherTimer as static class member or have a static Stop() method that stops it.